# LaTeX error using LyX: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, lyx, compiling, compilation-error, missing

I am using LyX as a LaTeX editor. I have a little file in my computer compiling normally in an old LyX version. Now I have a new computer and installed the latest LyX version (Lyx 2.3.4, 12 Jan 2020). But when compiling the files it gives me the error:

> Latex error missing \begin{document}

Here's the code of my file:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{xca}[thm]{\protect\exercisename}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{babel}




  \providecommand{\corollaryname}{Corollary}
  \providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}
  \providecommand{\lemmaname}{Lemma}
  \providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}
  \providecommand{\remarkname}{Remark}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{multicol}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi})}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{xca}{\large}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\footnotesize\(\bullet\)}
}

\makeatother

\providecommand{\exercisename}{Exercice}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Théorème}

\begin{document}
\global\long\def\norm#1{\left|#1\right|}%

\global\long\def\norme#1{\left|#1\right|}%

\global\long\def\sig{\sigma}%

\global\long\def\si{\sigma}%

\global\long\def\eps{\varepsilon}%

\global\long\def\ep{\varepsilon}%

\global\long\def\m{\mathcal{M}}%

\global\long\def\e{\mathcal{E}}%

\global\long\def\la{\lambda}%

\global\long\def\R{\mathbb{R}}%

\global\long\def\C{\mathbb{C}}%

\global\long\def\r{\mathbb{R}}%

\global\long\def\n{\mathbb{N}}%

\global\long\def\N{\mathbb{N}}%

\global\long\def\ph{\varphi}%

\global\long\def\b{\mathcal{B}}%

\global\long\def\normop#1{\left\Vert #1\right\Vert }%

\global\long\def\norop#1{\left\Vert #1\right\Vert _{\mathcal{T}}}%

\global\long\def\growth{\omega_{0}\left(\mathcal{T}\right)}%

\global\long\def\ess{\omega_{ess}\left(\mathcal{T}\right)}%

\global\long\def\nor#1{\left|#1\right|_{\mathcal{T}}}%

\title{\setstretch{0.5}\noindent }
\maketitle
\begin{xca}
\noindent \textbf{(12pts)}\textbf{ Les questions dans cet exercice
sont indépendantes.}\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Donner une primitive sur l'intervalle $]0,+\infty[$ de la fonction
$f(x)=\ln x$. \vspace{0.3cm}
\item Donner le développement limité \uline{en \mbox{$0$}} à \uline{l'ordre
\mbox{$2$}} de la fonction $f(x)=\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)$.\vspace{0.3cm}
\item Donner le développement limité \uline{en \mbox{$0$}} à \uline{l'ordre
\mbox{$3$}} de la fonction ${\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\text{ }e^{x}\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{e^{x}-1}}$.\vspace{0.3cm}
\item Donner le développement limité \uline{en \mbox{$+\infty$}} à \uline{l'ordre
\mbox{$1$}} de la fonction $f(x)={\displaystyle \frac{x^{2}+1}{x-2}}$.\vspace{0.3cm}
\item Calculer la limite ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin x\right)}{x^{3}}+\frac{x-2}{2x^{2}}\right)}$.\vspace{0.3cm}
\item Calculer la limite ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{x}{5x+e^{x}-\cos x}}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{xca}

\noindent \vspace{0.3cm}

\begin{xca}
\textbf{(8pts)}\vspace{0.3cm}

\noindent Soit $(u_{n})_{n}$ la suite définie pour tout entier naturel
$n\geq1$ par
\[
u_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+x^{n}\right)dx.
\]

\begin{enumerate}
\item Énoncer le Théorème Fondamental de l'Analyse.
\item Calculer $u_{1}$.
\item Montrer que pour tout $x\in]-1,+\infty[$
\[
\ln\left(x+1\right)\leq x.
\]
\item Montrer que pour tout entier naturel $n\geq1$
\[
0\leq u_{n}\leq\frac{1}{n+1},
\]
puis en déduire la limite ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty}u_{n}}$. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{xca}

\noindent 
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{Fin de l\textquoteright énoncé.}
\par\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After removing `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` your MWE works fine. Recent `article` default encoding is `utf8`.

Comment: @Zarko I don't know how to have access on that in Lyx.

Comment: Me either, if in the LyX you can not simple delete this code line.. Sorry, I'm not familiar with LyX.

Comment: Off-topic: In question 2.3., you should change `$x\in]-1,+\infty[$` to  `$x\in\mathopen{]}-1,+\infty\mathclose{[}$` in order to fix the horizontal spacing between `\in` and `]` and between `]` and `-`. (Without this adjustment, the spacing is messed up because the math status of the `]` symbol is `math-close` by default.)

Comment: @Mico Ah thanks, I am just using this file of a friend as a template. But thanks for the remark!!

Comment: It might be worth pointing out (though it is unlikely to be the cause of the problem here, since the MWE compiles OK for me once I fix the encoding) that it is dangerous to define macros with `\def` as that does not check if you are overwriting existing macros: It is better to use LaTeX's `\newcommand` unless you know exactly what you are doing. Doubly so if you define single-letter commands: Many of those are already taken by TeX, LaTeX or one of the standard packages and redefining them can cause serious troubles. ...

Comment: ...  There are many stories about people redefining `\i` and `\c` with `\def` who then end up wondering why they the names of their Turkish colleagues don't come out correctly in the bibliography. Is there any chance you could get hold of the complete `.log` file and share that with us? (`.log` files are usually too long for the character limit, but you can upload them to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @DavidLingard Can you post the .lyx file that created that .tex code you posted?

Comment: In my case, this happened when using acmart (ACM article). LyX issued `\maketitle` immediately after the title; due to acmart, this happened before `\begin{document}`. The solution was to put the abstract, authors, addresses and ACM classifcations *before* the  title. Then it worked. Weird but true.